# $n^2+np$ is a perfect square

Tags: number-theory

> Let $p > 2$ be a prime. Prove that there exists exactly one positive integer $n$ such that $n^2+np$ is a perfect square.

I tried bounding the expression $n^2+np$ between two perfect squares, but I wasn't able to because there was no constant term. We know that $n^2+np < \left(n+\frac{p}{2}\right)^2$, but I couldn't get a lower bound. How can we solve the question?

Answer (score 17):

First off we check that $p$ cannot divide $n$.  Note that if $n= pk$ then $n^2 + np = p^2(k^2+k)$.  Now this cannot be a perfect square because $k^2 < k^2+k < (k+1)^2$.

If $n$ is relatively prime to $p$, then $n+p$ is relatively prime to $n$, and $n^2+np = n(n+p)$ is a perfect square precisely when both $n$ and $n+p$ are squares.  If we write $n= i^2, n+p=j^2$, then $p = j^2-i^2 = (j-i)(j+i)$.  As $p$ is prime, we have $j-i=1, j+i = p$, so that $i = (p-1)/2$ and $j = (p+1)/2$.

This shows that $n = (p-1)^2/4$ is the only value for which $n^2+np$ is a perfect square.

Comment: Have the two upvoters actually read the answer in $17$ seconds ?

Comment: @Peter I was wondering the same thing, upvoted just now.

Comment: I'm not an upvoter / haven't read the answer.  But this is an important point to make @Peter.  All too often in my haste to post, I submit something *entirely* wrong.  I've found myself deleting answers of mine that garnered as many as $5$ upvotes without anyone pointing out my error. The peer-review facet of stack exchange is of fundamental importance to this site, IMO.  Anyways, sorry for my rant on your post Rolf.  Will delete this in a few minutes.

Comment: @KajHansen You shouldn't delete! This is not against Rolf, it is against the far too fast upvotes. Such fast upvotes happen often. And this is somehing that should be mentioned.

Comment: The answer definitely deserves the upvotes in this case, to clarify that.

Comment: @KajHansen What you described is not what should happen here. An upvote should be the result of a careful check of the answer. At the one hand, to detece possible errors, on the other hand to approve that it is a really useful answer. I find it good that you deleted the answers.

Comment: Absolutely @Peter; fortunately for me, the embarrassment of having written something wrong outweighs the little bit of gratification receiving more internet points.  I resolved about a year ago to always check the correctness of answers before upvoting, even if it means grappling with someone's reasoning for longer than I'd like.  Unfortunately, this means fewer points for people who have dedicated lots of time typing up something of great length and difficulty (and probably deserve their received upvotes), but I think it's better for the site this way.

Answer (score 3):

$$n^2+np=k^2 \to n^2+np-k^2=0\\
n=\frac{-p+ \sqrt{p^2+4k^2}}{2}$$

So,

$$p^2+4k^2=q^2\to p^2=(q-2k)(q+2k)$$

once $p>2$ is prime and $n>0$ (which means $k\ne 0$ and then $q-2k\ne q+2k$), then the only one possibility is write

$$q-2k=1\\
q+2k=p^2$$

what give us

$$q=\frac{p^2+1}{2}$$

and then

$$n=\frac{-p+ q}{2}=\left(\frac{p-1}{2}\right)^2$$

Answer (score 1):

Let's find *all* integers $n$ such that $n^2+pn$ is a square, then show that only one of of them is positive.

If $n^2+pn=m^2$ then $pn=(|m|-n)(|m|+n)$, so without loss of generality we can assume $m=n+pk$ for some integer $k$.  Now writing

$$n^2+pn=(n+pk)^2=n^2+2pkn+p^2k^2$$

we see

$$(1-2k)n=pk^2$$

But $\gcd(1-2k,k^2)=1$, so we must have $(1-2k)\mid p$.  This gives four possibilities (using the fact that $p$ is an odd prime):

$$\begin{align}
1-2k=1&\implies k=0\implies n=0\\
1-2k=-1&\implies k=1\implies n=-p\\
1-2k=p&\implies k={1-p\over2}\implies n=\left(1-p\over2\right)^2\\
1-2k=-p&\implies k={1+p\over2}\implies n=-\left(1+p\over2\right)^2\\
\end{align}$$

Only the third possibility has a positive value for $n$.